# .htaccess image to php redirect rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that gives you a random cat gif every time you refresh, and it works in image tags. Some forums won't let you put http://randomcat.tk in an image tag, so I was thinking I could use RewriteEngine so people can put http://randomcat.tk/cats.gif and have it redirect to index.php.

Sorry if that made no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

```
RewriteRule ^cats.gif$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: http://randomcat.tk/cats.gif gives an error. Going to try to add a legit image not just a blank cats.gif

Comment: The path segment of the URL that a RewriteRule in .htaccess context checks on _never_ starts with a `/` – so try without that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L]
```

this will redirect any request to index.php